# Python Dash - callback value from another file

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I create a dashboard based on flask and dash python
How can I refresh data pulled from another `.py` file with a specified interval?
I have a weather_api.py file that returns data from openweathermap API
and I refer to it such as:

```
html.Div(children=[
        html.Div(children=[html.Img(src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{}@2x.png".format(WEATHER_API.icon))]),
        html.Div(children=[html.H2("{} ".format(round(WEATHER_API.current_temperature))),
        html.Span(["Data", html.Br()]),
        html.Span("{}".format(WEATHER_API.weather_description))]),
        ])
])
```

at the beginning of the file I import `WEATHER_API` - and then it will refer to variables e.g.: `html.Span("{}".format(WEATHER_API.weather_description))` 
I would like this data to be refreshed every e.g. 10 minutes - now it works so that the data is only from the beginning - as soon as I run the Dash, it "pulls" data from the API only once. Is it possible to somehow set up `@callback` to retrieve data from `WEATHER_API` every 10 minutes - as if starting `WEATHER_API.py` every 10 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution - you can easily return a function value from another script - all you need is a proper reference:

```
import script.py

app.layout = html.Div(
    [

        html.Div(id="number-output"),
        dcc.Interval(id='interval-component',
interval=1000,  # in millisecondsn_intervals=0
        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output('number-output', 'children'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])

def update_output(n):
    return html.Span('Output: {}'.format(script.test()))
```

A useful example:
https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need the [interval](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval) component.

Here are [some examples](https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates) of it in use to provide live updates.

Comment: in this way I already update my charts - the problem is that I don't know how to update the data only - to `weather_api.py` I added a variable that returns the current time and app layout looks like `html.Div(id="number-output"), dcc.Interval(id='interval-component',interval=3000` and callaback like: `@app.callback(Output('number-output', 'children'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_output(n):
    return html.Span('Longitude: {}'.format(WEATHER_API.time)),` - the time is displayed, but WEATHER_API.time does not update every sec